# How to show upload progress in react admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

So I'm using react-admin https://marmelab.com/react-admin, and I want to show upload progress whenever I send files on create function.

```
import React from "react";
import { Create, SimpleForm, FileInput, FileField } from "react-admin";

export const PostFile = props => (
  <Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <FileInput source="pictures" label="Related files" multiple={true}>
        <FileField source="src" title="title" />
      </FileInput>
    </SimpleForm>
  </Create>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

react-admin uses 'optimistic rendering' so by the time you start uploading in the data provider probably your create or edit form where you had the file drag & drop will be gone so you can't display the progress bar in the same form. This is probably why it isn't part of the API...

But you could implement a simple global event emitter, that emits 'file upload progress' events from the data provider, and have the top-level App subscribe to those and update a progress value in local App state in the event handler, then have a notification kind of component that renders when you're in an uploading state showing that progress value. This has the advantage you don't need to change any redux.
react-admin does provide a 'useNotify' hook that you can use in data provider to show a notification, but it's only for simple text notifications.